# Eigenvalues within the unit circle

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $P$ be a positive $n×n$ matrix. That is $P_{ij} > 0,\ \forall i,j \in \{1,...,n\}$.

I am aware that if all row sums of $P$ are smaller than 1, then the Perron–Frobenius eigenvalue, the largest eigenvalue, will be smaller than 1 too. But I would like to know if there are sufficient conditions on $P_{ij}$ under which all eigenvalues of $P$ strictly lie within the unit disk in the complex plane even if some row sums are larger than 1?

Answer (score 2):

Of course there are.  For example, it's true if $P$ is upper or lower triangular and its diagonal elements are less than $1$.
Or if all column sums are less than $1$.
Or if there are positive numbers $s_i$, $i=1\ldots n$ such that all
$ \sum_{j} P_{ij} s_i/s_j < 1$ (or all $\sum_i P_{ij} s_i/s_j < 1$).

EDIT: As Ian pointed out, the upper and lower triangular matrices 
don't satisfy the requirement that $P_{ij} > 0$.  However, we can
modify these examples slightly: we write $P = T + N$ where $T$ is (upper or lower) triangular and nonnegative with all diagonal elements less than $1$.  Then  if $\|N\| < \|(I-T)^{-1}\|^{-1}$ (where $\|\cdot \|$ is a sub-multiplicative matrix norm), the Perron eigenvalue of $P$ is less than $1$.

Comment: All entries are requested to be strictly positive, so this does not satisfy the criterion.

Comment: Robert, I would appreciate if you could direct me to a reference for the last condition you mentioned ($s_i$s). 

Just for your information that why I am interested in learning sufficient conditions under which all eigenvalues of a strictly positive matrix lies within a unit circle, please see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1335179/how-to-modify-a-matrix-to-push-all-of-its-eigenvalues-into-the-unit-circle

Comment: It's just that $P$ is similar to (and thus has the same eigenvalues as) $S P S^{-1}$ where $S$ is the diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $s_i$.