# How to modify a matrix to push all of its eigenvalues into the unit circle?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a strictly positive $n \times n$ matrix. That is, $a_{ij} >0, \ \forall i,j \in \{1,...n\}$. If some of eigenvalues of $A$ are outside or on the unit circle, I was wondering if I can find an $n \times n$ matrix $B$ such that both of the following conditions are satisfied:

1) $B$ is element-wise larger than or equal to $A$. That is, $b_{ij} \geq a_{ij}, \ \forall i,j \in \{1,...n\}$.

2) all eigenvalues of $B$ are strictly within the unit circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't happen: the Perron eigenvalue is a nondecreasing function of the entries of the matrix.

Given  matrices $A$ and $B$ with all $0 < a_{ij} \le b_{ij}$, let $A(t) = A + t (B-A)$.  $A(t)$ has Perron eigenvalue $\lambda(t)$ with positive left and right eigenvectors $w(t)^T$ and $v(t)$.  Now differentiate the equation 
$A(t) v(t) = \lambda(t) v(t)$:

$$  \dfrac{dA}{dt} v(t) + A(t) \dfrac{dv}{dt} = \dfrac{d\lambda}{dt} v(t) + \lambda(t) \dfrac{dv}{dt} $$
Multiply on the left by $w(t)^T$, and subtract $w(t)^T A(t) \dfrac{dv}{dt} = \lambda(t) w(t)^T \dfrac{dv}{dt}$:
$$ w(t)^T \dfrac{dA}{dt} v(t) = \dfrac{d\lambda}{dt} w(t)^T v(t) $$

But $w(t)^T \dfrac{dA}{dt} v(t) \ge 0$ and $w(t)^T v(t) > 0$, so we conclude that $\dfrac{d\lambda}{dt} \ge 0$.  Thus $\lambda(1)$, the Perron eigenvalue of $B$, is greater than or equal to $\lambda(0)$, the Perron eigenvalue of $A$.

Answer (score 6):

It's certainly not always possible.

Look up the Perron-Frobenius Theorem. Every strictly positive matrix has a positive real eigenvalue *r* called the *Perron root* such that for all eigenvalues $\lambda$ of A $$|\lambda| \le r$$

The Theorem also gives that r is greater than or equal to the minimum row sum of the matrix. That is, if A = $a_{ij}$ is a strictly positive nxn matrix,
$$\min\limits_{i} \sum\limits_{j}a_{ij} \le r \le \max\limits_{i} \sum\limits_{j}a_{ij}$$

(The max part doesn't matter for this question).

So if your matrix A has a minimum row sum greater than 1, it will have a Perron root - and thus an eigenvalue - outside the unit circle. And your B clearly has minimum row sum greater than or equal to A's minimum row sum.

Given more info on A, your problem may be possible. But it's not always possible.

Comment: I understand your argument.

There are three situations:

1) The max row sum of $A$ is smaller than 1. In this case all eigenvalues of $A$ will be strictly within the unit circle.

2) The min row sum is larger than 1. In this case, as you said, at least one of eigenvalues of $A$ are outside the unit circle and my favorite $B$ does not exist.

3) Can we say any thing about the existence of $B$ if the min is less than 1 and the max is larger than 1?

Comment: Hmm, that's a very difficult problem. I would suggest looking at Gershgorin's circle theorem (the wikipedia article is very good). It gives areas in the complex plane that the eigenvalues must be contained in. In my graduate Lin Alg class, we talked about how this theorem is theoretically useful, but in practice the areas are often very large. Perhaps with certain constraints on A you may find it helpful.